# Making a loop stop when user presses a button

Tags: batch-file, autoit

Im looking for some sort of method of making a loop terminate when the user presses a button.  I understand that if you had a loop going, you could press control c, but that isn't what I want the user to have to do.  I don't think it's possible in a batch file, but I'm looking forwards to someone here proving me wrong!

I had another idea.  What about using an autoit script?  Where at the beginning of a batch file, you start autoit script.  The script uses the hotkey function, and when the hotkey is pressed the program closes.  Back in the batch file, you check every so often to see if the autoit script is running.  If its not, then you know that the hotkey was pressed.  **I have tested it, and it works, but I don't like the delay that is created every time I check the tasklist.exe for wkey.exe**.  If I could find a more efficient way to do this, that would be awesome!

Batch file:

```
@echo off
start wkey.exe
echo press the w key to stop.
timeout 3
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq wkey.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "wkey.exe">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 goto endloop
echo doing stuff . . .
goto loop

:endloop
echo you pressed the w key.
pause
exit
```

wkey.exe (programmed with the autoit language)

```
#NoTrayIcon
#include <Constants.au3>

HotKeySet("w", "_input")

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _input()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this and when you press the control (CTRL) key the loop will stop executing - it works on `32 bit machines` only and `certutil` isn't native to XP it seems so Vista and higher is required.

```
@echo off
>tmp.tmp echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>>tmp.tmp echo uEAAjtigFwC0TM0h
>>tmp.tmp echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----

certutil -decode -f tmp.tmp kbflag.com >nul

for /L %%a in (1,1,10000) do (
echo Press the CTRL key to exit - %%a
kbflag.com
if errorlevel 4 if not errorlevel 5 goto :skip
)
:skip
del kbflag.com
del tmp.tmp
echo Finished.
pause
```

It uses a magazine `.com` file utility (.com files work on 32 bit machines only) called `KBFLAG.COM` that monitors the keyboard and sets an errorlevel which you can branch on.

It is a 12 byte file in this order `B8 40 00 8E D8 A0 17 00 B4 4C CD 21` and the batch file creates and deletes it (it is encoded into the certificate data).

You may be able to find a similar tool for a `64 bit system` that is not a .com file.

Here is the document file:

```
KBFLAG -- by Nico Mark -- from PC Magazine, December 23, 1986 

KBFLAG can be used to cause branching in batch files, so that execution of
different parts of the file can be dependent on the state of toggle and shift
keys.  You can, for example, abort execution of AUTOEXEC.BAT if the CapsLock
key has been toggled while CONFIG.SYS in running.

KBFLAG tests for a keystroke in the buffer, and sets errorlevel to the value of
the key's KBFLAG in the ROM BIOS.  Thus, if the Ins key has been toggled, it
will return an errorlevel of 128.  Other values are:  

    1 = Right Shift 
    2 = Left Shift 
    4 = Ctrl key 
    8 = Alt key
       16 = ScrollLock 
       32 = NumLock 
       64 = CapsLock 
      128 = Ins 

(You can use sums of these values to correspond to combinations of keys, so
96 = CapsLock and NumLock together.) 

If you put these lines at the start of autoexec.bat-- 

    KBFLAG 
    IF ERRORLEVEL 64 GOTO :END 

--and put the label :END at the end of the file, autoexec.bat will then check 
to see if CapsLock has been pressed, and will jump the end of the batch if it
has.   To prevent autoexec.bat from executing on bootup, simply hit CapsLock
while  config.sys is running.     

You can use variations of this technique to cause different sets of programs
to run during autoexec.bat (or any batch file).  For example, Caps Lock could
cause only a few programs to run; Alt + CapsLock could cause others; etc.
```

Comment: I'm sure it works, but running a 64 bit system, It won't work for me.